# Prestashop Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

error:Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'vandrein_admin'@'193.108.130.12' (using password: YES)
at line 136 in file classes/db/DbPDO.php

so my website is online and i got absolutely no idea why it just stopped working. It was working fine around 4 days ago and no one touched it. Please tell me how i can fix the problem. I really don't want to do the installation again......[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52hpU.png)

im open to suggestions

Comment: _"no one touched it"_ This is probably not true. Most likely, either your password or your user's access rights to the database changed. It's possible your source IP changed, but not likely. Can you connect via the command line using that userid and password?